# find a point internal to an arbitrary polygon maximising the minimum distance to a vertex / edge

Tags: geometry

I have an irregular 2d (straight sided) polygon. I know the coordinates of each point.

I'm looking for a mathematical method to find a point internal to the polygon such that:

- the distance from the point to any point on the containing polygon is maximised and
- lines from the point to each vertex on the containing polygon create triangles

  - that are wholly inside the polygon
  - that have angles greater than some threshold value (i.e. don't have angles close to 0!)
  - that maximises the length of the shortest side over all triangles (i.e. is as far away as possible from a vertex)

(or, of course, to determine if there is no such point within the given polygon)

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Comment: For the first part (the distance from the point to any point on the containing polygon is maximized), are you asking for the centroid (center of gravity) of the irregular polygon? As long as the polygon isn't self-intersecting, perhaps this page can help (scroll down to the part about centroid): https://web.archive.org/web/20120229233701/http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polyarea/

Comment: hi, @AlexK thanks for the reply -  but nope the centroid is not helpful (I had tried that and a few other approaches from Wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid to get a "centre" - but none give the desired outcome). On the other point - it's not self intersecting (or rather it will be constrained not to be..!)

Comment: Also, this polygon is convex, correct?

Comment: not necessarily - could be concave too

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: [link]https://i.ibb.co/ypt4WsT/vanishing-Point.jpg that's the sort of thing I'm after -- find a place where the green paths converge and give "sensible" triangles